# net tcp configuration in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I am trying to implement Observer Design Pattern with WCF as Publisher and a console application as the Client. When I try to add the WCF service as a reference in the client i get the below error.

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:20814/MessageService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].]
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +6065812
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost) +701
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection) +69
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration() +162
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration() +178
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +184
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +46
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +235
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +32
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +524
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1420
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +641

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/MessageService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +488839
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +174
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +174
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +174
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +350822
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9670421
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9670421
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b> Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[InvalidOperationException]: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
[ServiceActivationException]: The service '/MessageService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]..
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
-->
--.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:20814/MessageService.svc'.
The requested service, 'http://localhost:20814/MessageService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

But I have defined net.tcp binding in the web.config of WCF which is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="AtlasCommunicationServer.MessageService">
        <endpoint address="MessageService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            contract="AtlasCommunicationServer.IMessageService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:20814" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The contract and the contract implementation is shown below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace AtlasCommunicationServer
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMessageServiceCallback))]
    public interface IMessageService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SendData(string UserID, string Message);
        bool Attach(string UserID, IMessageServiceCallback Callback);
    }

    public interface IMessageServiceCallback
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool Update(string Message);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Message
    {
        public string MessageData;
        public string UserID;

        public Message(string UserID, string MessageData)
        {
            this.UserID = UserID;
            this.MessageData = MessageData;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace AtlasCommunicationServer
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class MessageService : IMessageService
    {
        public Queue<Message> MessageQueue = new Queue<Message>();
        public Dictionary<string, IMessageServiceCallback> Notify = new Dictionary<string, IMessageServiceCallback>();

        public void SendData(Message _Message)
        {
            SendData(_Message.UserID, _Message.MessageData);
        }

        public void SendData(string _UserID, string Message)
        {
            if (Notify.Keys.Contains(_UserID))
            {
                try
                {
                    Notify[_UserID].Update(Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageQueue.Enqueue(new Message(_UserID, Message));
                    //TODO handle the exception
                }
            }
        }

        public bool Attach(string _UserID, IMessageServiceCallback _Callback)
        {
            if (!Notify.Keys.Contains(_UserID))
            {
                Notify.Add(_UserID, _Callback);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public bool Detach(string _UserID)
        {
            if (!Notify.Keys.Contains(_UserID))
            {
                Notify.Remove(_UserID);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

What am I missing here that the error shows up?

Comment: i think `<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />` missing in your configuration..

Answer (score 0):

Check your IIS / website configuration:

> Enabling Protocols: http,**net.tcp**

This is not website default configuration. You have to add 'net.tcp' to "Enabling Protocols" manualy.